# JAXB unmarshal returns non-root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to use the JAXB Unmarshaller to translate an xml document into a java object tree.

The XML document looks like this:

```
<Levels>
    <Level>
        <Solution>
            <Piece x="0" y="1">
                <Shape/>
                <Color/>
            </Piece>
            <Piece x="0" y="1">
                <Shape/>
                <Color/>
            </Piece>
        </Solution>
        <Clues>
            <Clue>
                <Piece x="0" y="0">
                    <Shape/>
                    <Color/>
                </Piece>
            </Clue>
            <Clue>
                <Piece x="0" y="0">
                    <Shape/>
                    <Color/>
                </Piece>
            </Clue>
        </Clues>
    </Level>
</Levels>
```

I created very basic classes to hold each component:

Levels.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Levels {

    private List<Level> levels = new ArrayList<Level>();

    @XmlElementRef(name="Level")
    public List<Level> getLevels() {
        return levels;
    }

    public void setLevels(List<Level> levels) {
        this.levels = levels;
    }
}
```

Level.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Levels")
public class Level {

    private Solution solution = new Solution();
    private Clues clues = new Clues();

    @XmlElementRef(name="Solution")
    public Solution getSolution() {
            return solution;
    }

        public void setSolution(Solution solution) {
        this.solution = solution;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(name="Clues")
    public Clues getClues() {
        return clues;
    }

    public void setClues(Clues clues) {
        this.clues = clues;
    }
}
```

The rest of the classes are formatted the same as these(same annotations and only getter and setter methods)

The code I use to unmarshal the xml is:

```
File file = new File("res/levelTest.xml");

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Levels.class);        
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

Object o = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);        
System.out.println(o);
```

The problem I am getting is that when I print the object, it prints `newXML.Solution@***` not `newXML.Levels@***` which is the root element. This means that the unmarshaller is returning an element other than the root element. I have searched google and stack overflow but I couldn't find an explanation for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an annotation conflict with your top-level class name and the name placed on the `Level` class.

You've annotated your `Level` class with the XmlElementRoot set to "Levels", which is actually the root element for your `Levels` class. Since you didn't specify it explicitly in your annotation for that class, the JAXB binding is returning a different mapping for your classes.

I created a quick mockup of your program, and was able to get it working properly with the following:

Levels class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Levels")
public class Levels {


    private List<Level> levels = new ArrayList<Level>();

    @XmlElementRef(name="Level")
    public List<Level> getLevels() {
        return levels;
    }

    public void setLevels(List<Level> levels) {
        this.levels = levels;
    }
}
```

Level class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Level")
public class Level {

    private Solution solution = new Solution();
    private Clues clues = new Clues();

    @XmlElementRef(name="Solution")
    public Solution getSolution() {
        return solution;
    }

    public void setSolution(Solution solution) {
        this.solution = solution;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(name="Clues")
    public Clues getClues() {
        return clues;
    }

    public void setClues(Clues clues) {
        this.clues = clues;
    }
}
```

Clues class (empty because I just needed a class definition):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Clues {
}
```

Solution class (same as above):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Solution {
}
```

Running the code using your input produces:

```
Levels@***
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was under the impression that all the @XmlRootElement annotation should point to the root.